# Implementar permissões em uma API REST asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-web-api

Estou implementando uma API em ASP.NET Core 2.0 no qual preciso implementar permissões, porém as formas que encontrei (Roles, Claims, Policies) me deixou bem confuso, pois a estrutura de permissões que preciso é bem mais simples do que as apresentadas.

Em meu modelo tenho duas classes, a classe Usuário e a Permissões, no qual elas tem um relacionamento N para N.

O que eu quero? Simplesmente Cadastrar cada permissão da tabela Permissões (Ex: "CadastrarUsuario", "ExcluirProduto", "AprovarPedido") e atrelar a cada usuário as permissões necessárias pra ele e com isto, minha API iria verificar no banco de dados a permissão do usuário de acordo com uma actionresult do meu controller.

Algo como:

```
[hasPermission("CadastrarUsuario")]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] Usuario usuario)
{
     ...
     ...
}
```

Alguém ja fez algo parecido, ou tem ideia de como posso fazer isto, sendo usando o IdentityCore ou outro método?

Comment: Não entendi, o que os roles do Identity não lhe atendem? você quer construir um membership provider do zero?

Comment: Eu não achei uma forma clara de como eu faria isto registrando as permissões no banco de dados. Porque eu terei usuários administradores que irão atribui e remover permissões de outros usuários cadastrados no sistema. Na verdade estou um pouco perdido nisso. Como eu faria pra fazer o relacionamento dos usuários cadastrados com as roles cadastrados no banco usando o Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com algumas pesquisas e muita leitura consegui resolver o meu problema e implementar o Identity em minha API.

Primeiramente você precisa alterar a herança da classe context de "DbContext" para "IdentityDbContext"

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Em seguida você precisa Criar uma Entidade para Herdar da classe IdentityUser que representa os usuários no qual serão utilizados para a autenticação e uma Entidade que herda da classe IdentityRole que representa as Roles.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
     ...
     ...
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Com estas implementações, ao criar a migration, irá criar o script que implementa as tabelas do Identity. Após atualizar o banco de dados, as tabelas do Identity foram criadas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isto, no método de autenticação precisei carregar as roles do usuário que está autenticando no momento e atribuir à um objeto da classe ClaimsIdentity. A seguir parte da implementação da minha classe de autenticação.

```
private IApplicationUserRepository _repository;
    private SigningConfigurations _signingConfigurations;
    private TokenConfiguration _tokenConfiguration;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserBusinessImpl(IApplicationUserRepository repository, 
                                        SigningConfigurations signingConfigurations, 
                                        TokenConfiguration tokenConfiguration,
                                        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                                        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _signingConfigurations = signingConfigurations;
        _tokenConfiguration = tokenConfiguration;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public object Login(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (applicationUser != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationUser.Email))
        {
            var userIdentity = _userManager
                .FindByEmailAsync(applicationUser.Email).Result;

            if (userIdentity != null)
            {
                var credentialsIsValid = _signInManager
                   .CheckPasswordSignInAsync(userIdentity, applicationUser.PasswordHash, false)
                   .Result;

                if (credentialsIsValid.Succeeded && userIdentity.Ativo)
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            new GenericIdentity(applicationUser.Email, "Email"),
                            new[]
                            {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userIdentity.UserName)
                            }
                    );

                    //Carregando as permissões do usuário para ser incorporado ao token
                    var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userIdentity).Result;

                    foreach (string role in roles)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                    }

                    DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime expirationDate = createDate + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_tokenConfiguration.Seconds);

                    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                    string token = CreateToken(identity, createDate, expirationDate, handler);

                    return SuccessObject(createDate, expirationDate, token);
                }
                else
                {
                    return ExceptionObject();
                }
            }

        }
        return ExceptionObject();
    }

    private string CreateToken(ClaimsIdentity identity, DateTime createDate, DateTime expirationDate, JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler)
    {
        var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = _tokenConfiguration.Issuer,
            Audience = _tokenConfiguration.Audience,
            SigningCredentials = _signingConfigurations.SigningCredentials,
            Subject = identity,
            NotBefore = createDate,
            Expires = expirationDate
        });

        var token = handler.WriteToken(securityToken);

        return token;
    }

    private object ExceptionObject()
    {
        return new
        {
            atenticated = false,
            message = "Falha na autenticação"
        };
    }

    private object SuccessObject(DateTime createDate, DateTime expirationDate, string token)
    {
        return new
        {
            atenticated = true,
            created = createDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            expiration = expirationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            accessToken = token,
            message = "OK"
        };
    }
```

Para testar a autenticação, criei uma classe para inserir algumas informações iniciais no banco de dados da API.

```
public class IdentityInitializer
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public IdentityInitializer(
        Context context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        GenerateRoles();

        CreateUser(
            new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "Administrador",
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true
            }, "Admin123!", "Administrador");

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Método para gerar todas as roles do sistema
    /// caso elas ainda não existam dentro do banco de dados
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateRoles()
    {
        //método para registrar todas as roles do sistema
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();

        //Listagem de todas as roles da API!
        roles.Add("Administrador");
        roles.Add("CadastrarUsuario");

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role).Result)
            {
                var resultado = _roleManager.CreateAsync(
                    new ApplicationRole
                    {
                        Name = role
                    }).Result;
                if (!resultado.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Erro durante a criação da role {role}.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateUser(
        ApplicationUser user,
        string password,
        string initialRole = null)
    {
        if (_userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Result == null)
        {
            var resultado = _userManager
                .CreateAsync(user, password).Result;

            if (resultado.Succeeded &&
                !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(initialRole))
            {
                _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, initialRole).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para restringir o acesso a um determinado controller da minha API, adicionei o seguinte atributo no cabeçalho do controller

```
[Authorize("Bearer", Roles = "Administrador")]
```

Com isto foi possível fazer o controle de acesso aos endpoints da minha api com as roles do Identity Core

**Referências**

[ASP.NET Core 2.0: JWT + Identity Core na autenticação de APIs](https://medium.com/@renato.groffe/asp-net-core-2-0-jwt-identity-core-na-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-apis-e2a6fab07421)

[Autorização em APIs ASP.Net Core](https://medium.com/tableless/autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-apis-asp-net-core-4f3648f5c28a)